# AngularJS dynamic background color changer validation errors

Tags: html, angularjs, compiler-errors, background-color

I want to create a dynamic background color changer. I found a lot of tutorials online, but none of them worked. This is the closest one so far. There is my code :

```
<h1>Background color changer</h1>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("Myapp", [])
app.controller("Mycontroller", function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [{
      name: 'Red',
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      name: 'Yellow',
      color: 'yellow'
    },
    {
      name: 'Pink',
      color: 'pink'
    },
    {
      name: 'Cyan',
      color: 'cyan'
    },
    {
      name: 'Orange',
      color: 'orange'
    }
  ]
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div ng-app="Myapp" ng-controller="Mycontroller">
            <select>
              <option value="" selected hidden>Select Color</option>
              <option ng-repeat="colorselect in colors" style="background-color:{{colorselect.color}}">{{colorselect.name}}</option>
          
          
            </select>
            <p>
              <a routerLink="/loggedinsettings">Go back</a>
            </p>
          
            <hr/>
          
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also showing 2 validation errors : [image: VSCode errors]

I turned off the Html > Validate: Styles in settings so the errors are no longer in VSCode. But They are still in Node.js when I run ng serve.

[image: ng serve]
[image: Website]

How can I fix that ? Thanks !

Comment: You appear to be mixing AngularJS and Angular, which are not the same. The code snippet you included is AngularJS, while the errors in your screen shots are from `ng serve`, which is an Angular tool.

Comment: Is that the problem ? That would be weird, Im doing it for school and the teacher told us to do it this way. What's the easiest way to fix that ?

Comment: AngularJS is a legacy framework which will no longer be updated as of the end of this year. I suspect that you were intended to do your work in the newer Angular framework. I would suggest that you first very which framework you should use. Then ensure that any examples you follow are using the correct framework.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your idea. I'll take a look tomorrow how to change it.